# Display the name of the channel where a message is deleted

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this function, how can I display the name of the channel where the message was deleted

```
bot.on("messageDelete", async(message) => {
let delEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  .setColor(colours.red_light)
  .addField("Author", message.author.tag, true)
  .addField("Message", message.content)
  .setTimestamp();
let loggingChannel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.id === "")
if(!loggingChannel) return;
loggingChannel.send(delEmbed)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let channelName = message.channel.name;
```

And then you can use that channel name variable wherever you want